# Why does setting IsFocused in ViewModel not focus the Entry in the View

Tags: xamarin.forms

It seems like the ViewModel gets an update of the Focused state of an Entry (based on user interaction) but setting a value on the bound property in the ViewModel has no effect.

I have this in my View:

```
<Entry IsFocused="{Binding Focused, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And this in my ViewModel:

```
public bool Focused
{
    get
    {
        return _focused;
    }
    set
    {
        _focused = value; // This gets invoked on user interaction with UI, but setting it programatically has no effect on the Entry's focus.
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Focused));
    }
}
```

Why is the above not working for me?

Is it because `IsFocussed` is read-only? If so, why am I even allowed to specify `Mode=TwoWay`?

Comment: Not finding this property `IsFocused` of `Entry`. Which version of XF used in project .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT XF v4.0. It does not come up for me in IntelliSense but it definitely compiles.

Comment: Okey, got it ! Glad you have solved it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public bool IsFocused
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsFocusedProperty); }
}
```

You guess right: the `IsFocused` property is indeed readonly.

They indeed could throw an exception in a setter, but design decisions are tough and must be coherent between all ui elements.